# WSO2 Api manager 1.10.0 security certificate

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I imported a pfx into wso2carbon.jks and it is partly working. the browser shows the security site, but when logging to publisher it throws out an exception.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like cert of the publisher is not available in the key manager node. Can u verify that?

Comment: Thanks, how can I verify it? the carbon and store console look good, the error only happens to publisher.